# Flutter http exception not throw on another try catch block

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, try-catch, flutter-http

I get into this weird exception which keeps on coming and freezing my app.
I am try to handle ***SocketException*** and ***TimeOutException*** in http package with provider package.

```
class Auth with ChangeNotifier{
..........
Future<User> getUser(String id) async {
try {
final user = (await http.post("${Domain.ADDRESS}/user",
      headers: {"auth-token": _token}, body: {"userId": id}))
  .body;
 } on SocketException {
 throw HttpException("DISCONNECTED");
 } on TimeoutException {
 throw HttpException("TIMEOUT");
}  catch (error) {
 print(error);
  throw HttpException("SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG");
  }
 notifyListeners();
 return userdata;
 }
   ......
 }
```

when internet in not connected application freezing at

```
on SocketException {
throw HttpException("DISCONNECTED");  <------------ Exception has occurred.
                                                  HttpException (DISCONNECTED)
```

But I handle this on next screen

```
 @override
  Future<void> didChangeDependencies() async {
 ......

 setState(() {
 isLoading = true;
 });
 try{
   user= await Provider.of<Auth>(context)
  .getUser(Provider.of<Auth>(context).userId);
 if (this.mounted) {
  setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });
    }
 
    }on HttpException catch(error){
    if(error.toString().contains("DISCONNECTED")){
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Please check your internet 
 connection"),));
    }
   }catch(error){
     print(error);
   }
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

Custom HttpException.dart

```
class HttpException implements Exception {
final String message;
HttpException(this.message);
@override
String toString() {
return message;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand you right, your IDE **pauses** when the exception is thrown, even though you **catch** it correctly.

Can you tell me what happens after resuming / unpausing the IDE that you're using, does it behave as expected and print this?

```
if(error.toString().contains("DISCONNECTED")){
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Please check your internet 
 connection"),));
```

Because if it does, that means that you probably have the **Breakpoints** setting on **All Exceptions** and not only **Uncaught Exceptions**.

[image: Image of visual code run tab]

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I found out that it was due to a bugged flutter beta/dev version that I had.

**Solution**
I fixed it by changing the channel to stable and upgrading to the newest version.

```
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
```

If you want, you can also change the channel to master to have the newest features of flutter. But I would really suggest using the stable channel, since it is more stable and beacause a new stable build was just recently released.

Here's a link to the issue that you're encountering:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66488

Comment: Its not working after following these instruction and also this issue [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66488) in ISO device . but I am use android .Is there any problem in code?

Comment: I wrote a new suggestion